# loop until a it enter a valid value in prolog

Tags: validation, prolog

I am new to prolog. I have only the very basic knowledge in Prolog.
I wrote this code in Prolog and I have no idea how to implement this part.

I want someone to enter his/her birthday and do other calculations based on his/her birthday. Before calculating the value I want to validate what he/she enters.

For example I wrote this code:

```
go:-write('Enter your name:'),nl,
    read(Name),nl,
    write('Enter your birth year:'),nl,
    read(Year),nl,
    write('Enter your birth month:'),nl,
    read(Month),nl,
    write('Enter your birth date:'),nl,
    read(Date).
```

and so on.

I know how to validate the above inputs. But what I want to know is how to loop through the entering process until it enters a valid value. For example if the user enters an invalid year it should display an error message (e.g., invalid year) and should let him/her enter it again without starting from the beginning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another alternative is to use `repeat` for going back if the input is invalid. And you can write a predicate patterned for user input with prompts:

```
read_input(Prompt, Value, CheckPred, ErrorMsg) :-
    repeat,
        format('~w:~n', [Prompt]),
        read(Value),
        (   call(CheckPred, Value)
        ->  true, !
        ;   format('ERROR: ~w.~n', [ErrorMsg]),
            fail
        ).

go :-
    read_input('Enter your name', Name, check_name, 'Invalid name'),
    read_input('Enter your birth year', Year, check_year, 'Invalid year'),
    read_input('Enter your birth month', Month, check_month, 'Invalid month'),
    read_input('Enter your birth date', Date, check_date, 'Invalid date'),
    % Do stuff with Name, Year, Month, Date...
    .
```

And create checker predicates:

```
check_name(Name) :- ...

check_year(Year) :- ...

check_month(Month) :- ...

check_date(Date) :- ...
```

You could easily extend this so that `check_name` also does some "fix-ups" like capitalizing names. (You'd have `check_...` take two arguments, etc.)

**ADDENDUM - Argument Check w/Fix-up**

```
read_input(Prompt, Res, CheckPred, ErrorMsg) :-
    repeat,
        format('~w:~n', [Prompt]),
        read(Value),
        (   call(CheckPred, Value, Res)
        ->  true, !
        ;   format('ERROR: ~w.~n', [ErrorMsg]),
            fail
        ).

% Check argument, and provided "fixed-up" argument xxxOut

check_name(Name, NameOut) :- ...

check_year(Year, YearOut) :- ...

check_month(Month, MonthOut) :- ...

check_date(Date, DateOut) :- ...
```

I would, however, recommend allowing the user to enter an entire date and parse that. SWI Prolog has some date predicates you can use for that purpose. You could then replace year, month, and date, with just date above, and for your `DateOut` you could use a term such as `birthdate(Month, Day, Year)`.

Comment: yep that is a problem. what if i want to pass two arguments to check_date predicate like check_date(Month,Date). how can i do it. please help me

Comment: @luker can u tell me how to fix the above problem??

Answer (score 2):

You can use tail-recursion if the entered value is not ok:

```
get_data(X,Y) :-
    ask_user(Z,T),
    (validate(Z,T) ->
        (X = Z, Y = T);
        get_data(X,Y)).
```

The `c -> t ; f` is an if-then-else pattern. If the condition `c` is met, `t` is executed (thus binding the entered data with the parameters), if not, you use tail recursion in order to retry this.

You can of course argue that this call will increase the stack, but advanced Prolog compilers won't create an additional call frame on the call stack if you perform tail-recursion.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a predicate, and call it recursively until getting a correct answer :

```
read_name(Name) :-
    write('Your name: '),
    read(TmpName),
    ((atom_codes(TmpName, L), length(L, N), N > 5) -> 
        (Name = TmpName) ; 
        (write('Error!'), nl, read_name(Name))
    ).
```

Here I just check if the name contains at least 6 charcters (`N > 5`), but you can replace it by whatever you want.

The syntax for if else is :

```
(Conditions -> ActionIfTrue ; ActionIfFalse)
```

Comment: This may be a stupid question. What if the user enter his/her name in capital. is there any way to get the name starting with a capital letter.

Comment: @Daybreaker If you're using swipl, you can use built-in predicates `upcase_atom`. `Name = salut, upcase_atom(Name, NU), string_to_list(NU, [H|_]), string_to_list(Name, [_|T]), string_to_list(CapName, [H|T]).` Maybe there is a better way than converting the whole string to uppercase to get the first char, but I didn't find one.